# No output when trying to redirect standard and/or error. How can i read the output from this?

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, redirectstandardoutput

When i try to redirect output from a executable running in batch mode there are only a few lines that shows up and there are no more output. Although i have set the window to not be visible it pops up anyway, but there are no output in the window so clearly the output are redirected but not showing.

The executable is normally started like this: `RustDedicated.exe -batchmode +more +arguments +here`

Now, when i try to spawn the exe file within my C# application only the very first lines outputs in debug console, the actual application window does not output anything.

Here are some code:

```
Process serverProcess;

private void StartServerThread()
{
    var serverArguments = GenerateServerArguments();
    var serverExecutable = Properties.Settings.Default.Rustserverexecutable;
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(serverExecutable),
            FileName = serverExecutable,
            Arguments = "-batchmode",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            //WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden //Application window show no mather what.
        };
        serverProcess = new Process();
        serverProcess.StartInfo = info;
        serverProcess.OutputDataReceived += ServerProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        serverProcess.ErrorDataReceived += ServerProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
        serverProcess.Start();
        serverProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        serverProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        //serverProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(serverExecutable + serverArguments); // I tested with cmd.exe and feeding it the path to the executable with arguments, same result.

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Also, as i have commented in the code i have tried to start CMD in interactive mode `/K` and the feeding it the path to the executable, and i have tried to redirect from a batch file wich does the same. Same result.

I have tried both ErrorData and OutputData.

Here are the code for that:

```
private void ServerProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data.ToString()))
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            txt_ServerMessage.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("ErrorData: "+e.Data.ToString())));
        }));
    }
}

private void ServerProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data.ToString()))
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            txt_ServerMessage.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(e.Data.ToString())));
        }));
    }
}
```

The Game server is working, but no output to work with.

What can be the reason of this? How can i successfully redirect the output?

Comment: You *do* know you can copy/paste text from a command window, right? Text is much easier to read than the content of images, and much more friendly to mobile users or those who are vision-impaired. It's also much easier to copy/paste text than it is to capture/save/upload images. There was no need for either of the images you posted.

Comment: Thanks Ken White, did not think of it like that. I have made som edits to the question.

Answer (score 0):

it's still actual for me.
Also work on automation work with Rust server, RustDedicated.exe.
So I ended up with usage of RestDedicated.exe -logfile output.txt, and watching it.

node.js TS example:

```
let pipe_file = 'output.txt';
const server_process = spawn('RustDedicated.exe', ['-batchmode', '-logfile', pipe_file],
{
    windowsHide: false,
    cwd: path.dirname(server_exe),
    shell: true,
    detached: true,
});
const pipe_full_path: string = path.join(path.dirname(server_exe), pipe_file);
let tail = new Tail(pipe_full_path);
fs.watchFile(pipe_full_path, (cur, prev) => {
    console.log(prev.mtime, cur.mtime);
});

tail.on("line", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});

tail.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});
```